# transform skew CSS

Tags: css, css3, вёрстка

Как выровнять текст в div, чтобы он не был наклоненный (без задания элементу p cвойства tranform:skew)? Пытаюсь назначить transform: none; или transform: unset; не помогает.

```css
div
{
  transform:skew(40deg);
  width: 50%;
  background: yellow;
  text-align:center;

}
```

```html
<div><p>Некоторый текст</p><div>
```

Comment: Никак. Вам не просто на ноль сбросить нужно, а трансформировать в обратную сторону.

Comment: Иногда такие вопросы встретишь...  Блин, дело не мое, но вот объясни на кой  надо выровнять текст что бы не задавать "р"  tranform:skew... ну если это так надо, то возьми в обертку  засунь и "p" и "div", что бы были параллельны и транформируй только div///

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Пример**

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}

div:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  transform: skew(40deg);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Некоторый текст</p>
</div>
```

Вариант с **clip-path**

Поддержка браузерами `clip-path` - [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path)

Для IE можно использовать [clip-path polyfill](https://github.com/AlfonsoFilho/ClipPath)

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  background: yellow;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 95% 0, 100% 100%, 5% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 95% 0, 100% 100%, 5% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Некоторый текст</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

```css
    div
    {
      transform:skew(40deg);
      width: 50%;
      background: yellow;
      text-align:center;

    }
    
    div p{
    transform: skew(-40deg);
    }
```

```html
<div><p>Текст</p></div>
```

Comment: Вы задание читаете вообще?

Comment: А чем Ваш ответ отличает от неправильного ответа выше?