# Корректное отображение блоков при наведении

Tags: javascript, html, css

При наведении на фото - появляются 2 наклонных блока. Не могу сообразить как выровнять текст по центру горизонтально вертикально (на пересечении блоков) и сделать его прямым (он наклонный из-за свойства transform: skew ). Лучше сделать через псевдоэлементы (т.к делаю галерею, нужно меньшее количество элементов)

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
.gallery__item {
  position: relative;
  background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8f/Bachalpsee_reflection.jpg/300px-Bachalpsee_reflection.jpg");
  height: 271px;
  width: 33.3%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.gallery__item:hover:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -8%;
  right: -11%;
  content: "";
  width: 80%;
  height: 65%;
  border-radius: 30px;
  transform: skew(-15deg);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.7);
}
.gallery__item:hover:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -8%;
  left: -11%;
  color: #fff;
  content: "Увеличить";
  text-align: right;
  width: 80%;
  height: 65%;
  border-radius: 30px;
  transform: skew(-15deg);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.7);
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery__item"></div>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат этого вопроса https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/744358/transform-skew-css

Comment: нет, мне нужно только через псевдоэлементы. Наверное, не за чем вставлять текст "увеличить" после каждого блока с картинкой в будущей галерее

Comment: `:before` - использовать картинку (`background`), а в `:after` текст. Всё.

Comment: Ну да можно и так, а если в дальнейшем понадобится анимировать каждый блок. Нужно более гибкое решение

Answer (score 1):

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
.gallery__item {
    position: relative;
    background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8f/Bachalpsee_reflection.jpg/300px-Bachalpsee_reflection.jpg");
    height: 271px;
    width: 33.3%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.gallery__item:hover:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: -8%;
    right: -11%;
    content: "";
    width: 80%;
    height: 65%;
    border-radius: 30px;
    transform: skew(-15deg);
    background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.7);
}

.gallery__item:hover:after {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -8%;
    left: -11%;
    content: "";
    text-align: right;
    width: 80%;
    height: 65%;
    border-radius: 30px;
    transform: skew(-15deg);
    background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.7);
}

.gallery__item:hover div:after {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    content: "Увеличить";
    color: #fff;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Online store</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Online store</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="gallery__item">
        <div></div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

По другому никак

Comment: Хитро :) а если js вставлять? или это совсем костыль)

Comment: Когда писал это "По другому никак" тожe про js подумал да в тэгах его нет да и js я не знаю:( ;)

Answer (score 0):

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
.gallery__item {
  position: relative;
  background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8f/Bachalpsee_reflection.jpg/300px-Bachalpsee_reflection.jpg");
  height: 271px;
  width: 33.3%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.gallery__item:hover:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: #fff;
  content: "Увеличить";
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 55%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery__item"></div>
```

Comment: поправил вопрос, может быть не хватало деталей

Comment: Пересечение блоков - обязательно? Можно обойтись одним псевдоклассом

Comment: Обязательно, в этом-то вся и сложность. Просто с текстом гораздо легче

Comment: Тогда надо понимать задачу глубже, чем описано в вопросе. Пока не понимаю, зачем такая сложность, если можно проще...

Comment: Согласен. Верстаю по макету, возможно дизайнер нарисовал не обоснованно сложный элемент

Comment: С дизайнером не поспоришь:)